# A Net::SMTPFatalError occurred , 550 Relaying denied

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I am getting this error message in my Production environment.  This is coming during the User creation and as the user is created a mail goes to the user with the Password and other details

```
Net::SMTPFatalError occurred in users#create:

  550 Relaying denied
```

Any Idea on this?

Comment: The error message is self explanatory. Check your mail server's config.

Comment: the mail server is sending mail, but for one of the specific id's let say 'abx@XXX.com" it's not sending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This worked for me:**

The servers MIP (Mapped IP) address needs to be added to the mail router's relay list. It was not added and that was the reason it was rejecting.  The receiver IP address was added and the mail was sent again.